# 401 error on iis when uploading files via PHP

Tags: php, iis-7

I have an upload script that runs on a windows webserver 2008. The uploads works nice, the file is created on the server. But when I try to access the uploaded image file via http, I just get an error 401. How can I resolve this?

EDIT: setting the chmod to 0777 after the file has been uploaded did not help, too.

Comment: have you tried to clear-private data? Maybe what the your browser is pulling off your web-server is old and has not found the new file?

Comment: aforloney, I thought that first, but that didnt help.

Comment: Might be a silly question but did you move it out of the temp directory once uploaded?

Comment: Cups, yes it is in the correct directory. Mind, it is not 404, it is 401 - permission denied.

Comment: what's the user and group of the uploaded files? is your upload code short enough to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That did it: https://serverfault.com/questions/85983/iis-iusrs-cannot-access-files-uploaded-and-created-by-network-service-error-401/229151#229151

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, many websites sequester uploaded files until they are validated, at which time they are made publicly accessible.  If this is the cause, you'd have to ask the site's administration.

Comment: I am the adminstrator. ;)
What do I need to do, so that my files are accessible at once after upload?

Comment: Is the target website windows webserver 2008 as well?  If so, I don't have a clue....

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize : one of the solutions is :

Edit `"upload_tmp_dir"` inside of `php.ini` and for example set to `"C:\my_temp_folder"`

Than right click to folder and security tab than  give `modify` permission to the `IUSRS` user  ;)